# What am I doing wrong with my query syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert a row into my table with the following query in ssms:

```
INSERT INTO [Reservation].[dbo].[Contacts]
       ([ContactID]
       ,[Name]
       ,[Phone]
       ,[Email]
       ,[QoowayUserName])
VALUES
       (<"100", nvarchar(50),>
       ,<"Vincent Chase", nvarchar(50),>
       ,<"3103331234", nvarchar(50),>
       ,<"vincent_chase@hollywood.com", nvarchar(50),>
       ,<"Username", nvarchar(50),>)
GO
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

I've also tried using single quotes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow. Remove every `[`,`]`,`<`,and `>` . And remove `GO`.

Comment: Is this really MySQL? Are you're sure that's what you're using? There is no `nvarchar()` in MySQL.

Comment: Wherever you learned this is mysql syntax from, ban it from future use

Comment: I think you picked up a book on SQL Server by accident. MySQL doesn't work like this **at all**. What are you doing wrong? Basically everything. You need a better reference. The good news is the [documentation on `INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) is very clear.

Comment: I do like the use of "Vincent Chase". Entourage was a good show. (I also offered a possible answer below.)

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You're using the wrong syntax.  As @tadman pointed out, that's T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Reservation.dbo.Contacts
   (ContactID
   ,Name
   ,Phone
   ,Email
   ,QoowayUserName)
VALUES
   ('100'
   ,'Vincent Chase'
   ,'3103331234'
   ,'vincent_chase@hollywood.com'
   ,'Username')
```

You might need to remove the "dbo", like this:

```
INSERT INTO Reservation.Contacts
   (ContactID
   ,Name
   ,Phone
   ,Email
   ,QoowayUserName)
VALUES
   ('100'
   ,'Vincent Chase'
   ,'3103331234'
   ,'vincent_chase@hollywood.com'
   ,'Username')
```

Comment: I'm not sure `dbo` is correct here. It should probably be `INSERT INTO Contacts`.